# How does System.out implement console output of characters?

Tags: java

I recently read that System.out and System.in are PrintStreams that are byte stream classes i.e they deal with bytes. Then how can they read inputs and write outputs as characters when Java uses 16-bit Unicode characters?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious mistake we make, when we look at above such docs/tutorial is, how `System.in/out/err` are dealing with bytes array, and what we assume, a byte is a character.

> Think like this, **A byte is just a 8 bits of 0/1** value and there is a char
>   type, which is actually character made up of two bytes. i.e. 16 bits.

[Oracle doc: Java primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

---

Then how does System.in/out/err deals with bytes?

The thing is they are of implementaion of class like `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, using sevices of these apis/implementations, we will be seeing **actual characters** read/write on to our console.

Basically they use [CharsetEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) apis to achieve these things. As per the docs,

```
/**
 * An engine that can transform a sequence of sixteen-bit Unicode characters 
 * into a sequence of bytes in a specific charset.
 * ... ...
 */
public abstract class CharsetEncoder
```

Also check this doc, it explains how the [unicode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/supplementary-142654.html) is handled in Java.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I always thought that these byte streams follow some automatic 16-bit Unicode to 8-bit Ascii conversions for displaying characters in our console. I will read the unicode doc that you have advised me.

Comment: No problem. Also read `CharsetEncoder` JavaDoc, you may get more clarity.